# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at drawChart

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, charts, google-visualization

```
//Ajax call
$(document).ready(function (data) {
  $("#btnGo").click(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: JSON.stringify({ startDate: $("#one").val(), endDate: $('#two').val() }),
      success: function (data) {
        
       
        var x = [data.x.count, data.x2.count, data.x3.count, data.x4.count]
        //data.x.count is getting from an api call where it will show count like 5
        drawChart(x)
        
      }

    });
  });
});
//bar chart
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(x) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Tickets', 'Count', { role: "style" }],
    ['x1', x[0], "#b87333"],
    ['x2', x[1], "silver"],
    ['x3', x[2], "gold"],
    ['x4', x[3], "green"]    
  ]);
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Tickets",
    width: 750,
    height: 550,
    bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

1. i have defined this chart outside the ajax function
2. whenever i am calling server i am getting error in developer console(script.js:96 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at drawChart)
3. after entering parameters and calling n number of times i am not seeing any errors in console
   4)whenever i run server i dont want to see error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you've discovered, the function gets called from the callback method without the data.
however, it is not a good idea to remove the callback,
as it is possible that the function may be called before google charts has fully loaded.
which would cause other errors.

there are a few ways to ensure google charts has loaded.
we can use the promise the `load` method returns.

as well, the `load` method will wait for the page to load by default.
so we can use google's `load` method in place of jquery's `ready` method.

recommend the following changes to ensure google charts has fully loaded,
and that the data gets properly passed to the chart.

```
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
}).then(function () {
  var options = {
    title: "Tickets",
    width: 750,
    height: 550,
    bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart"));

  $("#btnGo").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: JSON.stringify({ startDate: $("#one").val(), endDate: $('#two').val() })
    }).done(function (data) {
      var x = [data.x.count, data.x2.count, data.x3.count, data.x4.count];
      //data.x.count is getting from an api call where it will show count like 5
      drawChart(x);
    });
  });

  function drawChart(x) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Tickets', 'Count', { role: "style" }],
      ['x1', x[0], "#b87333"],
      ['x2', x[1], "silver"],
      ['x3', x[2], "gold"],
      ['x4', x[3], "green"]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    }, 2]);

    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank u WhiteHat,  can u please tell how to load 4 different charts

Comment: you only need one `load` statement, you can create as many charts as needed in the same place as the chart is created above. if you have issues, please edit the question and we can take a look...

Comment: added ur answer,you know javascript and nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line:

```js
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

This line will call your function `drawChart` without parameters. But it needs `x` to works properly, as you use it when you call `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`.

You don't need it as you will call drawChart in your Ajax callback.

Comment: i removed this google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); now not showing error. thank u Dreaken

Answer (score 0):

Scratch what i wrote earlier...
I did not see this line

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

that gets called when the google chart is loaded but you're not passing x..

Comment: inside ajax i used drawchart(x), i am getting output while i run the server firsttime i am getting this error

Comment: i removed this google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); now not showing error. thank u schwitter

Answer (score 0):

i removed this google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); now not showing error.