# How to return json object and view tgt from mvc controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, google-visualization

I am doing an MVC application where i need to pass json object from controller to view.

```
 public ActionResult VisualizeResult(int? id)
        {
            using (var context = new DBQUIZEntities())
            {
                context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                List<Choices> stdResult = context.Choices.Where(x => x.QuestionID == id).ToList();
                return Json(stdResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

The above code i am using in my controller , when i pass data to this view and open it. it return me a json string.(i understand because that no return view , so it return a json but if i change it to view) like i have no idea how to use this data  in my view function.

```
  List<Choices> stdResult = context.Choices.Where(x => x.QuestionID == id).ToList();
                // return Json(stdResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return View(stdResult);
```

my view

```
<head>
    <title>Result Visualization</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: '@Url.Action("VisualizeResult", "Home")',
                success: function (result) {
                    google.charts.load('current', {
                        'packages': ['corechart']
                    });
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                        drawChart(result);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        function drawChart(result) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Vote');
            var dataArray = [];


            $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
                dataArray.push([obj.ChoiceText, obj.VoteCount]);
            });
            data.addRows(dataArray);

            var columnChartOptions = {

                width: 1000,
                height: 400,
                bar: { groupWidth: "20%" },
            };

            var columnChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document
                .getElementById('piechart_div'));

            columnChart.draw(data, columnChartOptions);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Now i want to return my view page with this json string how can i do that by changing the view or controller.
my aim its to display the result in google chart.

Comment: Do you want the page rendered server side or do you want to consume the json via asynchronous ajax ?

Comment: if you console.log(result) in the callback, does it log the data?

Comment: I don't use .net, but couldn't you use two, one that returns json, and the other the view. then call the one that returns json from the other? also, I would recommend loading google first, then calling ajax, this would allow you to call ajax multiple times without re-loading the page. you can use google's load statement in place of jquery's ready statement. see the setup in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63057738/5090771)...

Comment: I did try use two, but fail. maybe its because i dont know how to pass over the data in script @WhiteHat

Comment: @Vince i dont get what you mean , sorry im new to javascript. by right if use first controller it did pass the json. but no the view

Comment: @ironman, i would then start by understanding how ajax calls work. The fist point to sort out is, does the data get returned in the success calback. You can see if this by adding a console log in the mentioned callback

Comment: @Vince  if i dont pass in parameter, controller just set question id == 2003.  and return json. when i open view and call the action able to display the google chart and if add in console.log will get the array.   but if i change return json to return view nothing display.

Comment: Ok, so you need to have a action to return the view that is separate from the one returning the json

Comment: @Vince i understand this if no  need pass in parameter. but if i expect to pass in parameter some thing like question id. instead i just state it ==2003. it no able to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

1. Home/Index will be returning view, you can set your router accordingly
2. Home/VisualizeResult will return json data on ajax call

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            return view("chart");
        }
        public ActionResult VisualizeResult(int? id)
        {
            List<Choices> stdResult = GetResult(id, ref context);
            return Json(stdResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private static List<Choices> GetResult(int? id, ref DBQUIZEntities context)
        {
            using (var context = new DBQUIZEntities())
            {
                context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                List<Choices> stdResult = context.Choices.Where(x => x.QuestionID == id).ToList();
                return stdResult;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for ans , but how i pass over the data by button <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Home",new { id=question.QuestionID})">View Result</a> its it like this ?

Comment: You can pass like this: `<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id=question.QuestionID})">View Result</a>`

or configure route from, App_Start >> RouteConfig.cs

Comment: it return a json no the chart view [{"Questions":null,"ChoiceID":1,"ChoiceText":"a for question1","QuestionID":1,"VoteCount":9,"TextAns":null,"Rating":null,"ThisDateTime":null},{"Questions":null,"ChoiceID":2,"ChoiceText":"b for question 1","QuestionID":1,"VoteCount":5,"TextAns":null,"Rating":null,"ThisDateTime":null}]

Comment: View code its on top i just copy and past into Home View

Comment: ok, so as I understand you want to load first time 'the myview code as on top' and then click of button want to load the chart by fetching data?

Comment: yes , its like a button when i click , it pass over the question ID and open the view which load the list and display in google chart.

Comment: ok, but it seems you are loading the data on document.ready `$(document).ready` not on button click

Comment: On this page its automatically run. i dk how to explain. it like theres a table showing question on page.cshtml view.  in the table there is a button view result . i expect clicking on view result button will jump to this result .cshtml page and display the chart.  i cant pass over the question id by controller or other way that i know so far.

Comment: Ok got it. Say the first page where there is Table is Table.cshtml. From Table.cshtml you want to go to Chart.cshtml. You can have button in Table.cshtml like this `<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Chart", new { id=question.QuestionID})">View Result</a>`. So the button at Table.cshtml will redirect the request to Chart controller, Index action method, from Index action method you can return 'Chart' view wich will contain your ajax call to Chart controller, VisualizeResult action method. I changed the code which should match your Chart controller. ok?

Comment: Erm thank you , now its like onlick button it able to jumo to the chart.view page. but the id look like never pass into the Getresult method since it return no data

Comment: Can you open browser debugger console (F12) and go to Networking tab. Then click on the button, you will see the request is being logged. Click on the request and check the header tab >> Request section if id is passed null/undefined, can you paste the request details as well.

Comment: i did follow waht you said but i didnt find a file name request.But if i open the VisualizeResult on preview show[]

Comment: can we do google meet call, I will be able to understand better